# Hi can someone help in html5 grayscale conversion code?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I can't find the bug here. I don't know where I missed something that is not making my code convert the image to gray scale. It would be helpful if someone can try this code and help me figure out the problem.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Canvas API</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- In order to have canvas we need to use the canvas tag  -->
    <canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <!-- To use canvas we need to access is from javascript code -->
    <script>
      var c = document.querySelector("#c"); // grab a canvas with id="c"
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d"); // context in which we are using it

      var img = new Image();
      img.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5397/rhino.jpg';

      img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        img.style.display = 'none';
      };

      var myData = ctx.getImageData(0,0, 500, 500);
      console.log(myData);



      var grayscale = function(imageData) {
        var numPixels = imageData.data.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < numPixels; i+=4) {
          var avg = 0.34 * imageData.data[i] + 0.5 * imageData.data[i + 1] + 0.16 * imageData.data[i + 2];
          imageData.data[i*4+0] = avg;
          imageData.data[i*4+1] = avg;
          imageData.data[i*4+2] = avg;
          // imageData.data[i*4+3] = 255;
        }
        ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
      };

      grayscale(myData);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code to find out where in specific the problem is?

Comment: This looks like the image probably hasn't loaded before you're trying to modify the canvas, move your data get and greyscale into the load callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't just one bug in your code. We already found 4:

1. You need to set the `.onload` handler before you set the `.src` attribute. When the image is already in the browser cache, the image is loaded the moment the .src attribute is set. Setting an onload handler when the image is already loaded does nothing.
2. You are getting the imagedata and call the `greyscale()`-function without checking if the `.onload` handler was already executed, so when the image *isn't* cached, your greyscale function will likely execute before the onload-handler drew the image to the canvas. When you want to make sure your greyscale-conversion code is executed after the image was drawn, move that code into the onload-handler after `ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);`.
3. In the `greyscale` function, when you set the `imageData.data`, you multiply `i` with 4, but you don't when you read the data. That means you write other pixels than you read. You are already incrementing `i` by 4 in the for-loop, so that multiplication should not be required.
4. You are loading an image from a remote domain (`mdn.mozillademos.org`). The moment you draw a remote image to a canvas, the canvas becomes "tainted by cross-origin data" and certain functionality like `getImageData` is disabled for security reasons. Copy the image to the same domain where your script resides. (thanks, @NiettheDarkAbsol)

By the way: A `new Image()` is not shown anywhere unless you insert the newly created image node into the DOM tree of the websites document. You don't do this in your code. So `img.style.display = 'none';` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: You're missing the biggest problem of all: loading a remote images taints the canvas, and you cannot call `getImageData` on a tainted canvas.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thank you, I added this.

Comment: Thanks Phillipp it was really helpful, I could finally make it work.

Comment: @varun When I was able to help you, please accept this answer by clicking the check-mark icon next to it.